# Very slow building time of Webpack on production, fast on development

Tags: webpack, dev-to-production, webpacker

After switch to webpack (resp. Rails + Webpacker gem) compiling bundle on production server is more then 10 times longer than on development.

Production machine is better than development, required modules are the same.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found that `resolve-url-loader` module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader) + folder with many uploaded images (into separate folders) was the brake.

`resolve-url-loader` searches for CSS `url('my_image')` in whole folder from which `webpack` was run. And one of subfolders was the million-subfolders-folder. So loader try to search in every corner.

I do not find any option to exclude this folder from search by config.
But! If loader finds file `package.json` or `bower.json` in folder, it will stop searching. So solution was to `touch million-subfolders-folder/package.json`.
It is not perfect, loader still search content of folder for each, not yet founded, image. But just once, not searching trough million subfolders.

Comment: In the config where you use "resolve-url-loader" you should be able to add a folder exclusion. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-exclude

Comment: I tried, but no success. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It is kinda complicated, when you have to modify default config of Webpacker gem.

Comment: @Foton can I ask you, how do you profile webpack compilation to find out that the problem was with that module? We also have such kind of problem but can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: From mastermind @virus, who found it: This particular problem was identified by common linux utilities. `iotop` identified, that webpacker compilation creates lots of iops. The we used `strace` to look for syscalls -directory listing.